# d3 how to turn a set of numbers into a larger set representative of the first set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Say I have array [1,2,5,18,17,8] and I want to turn that into an array of length 40 that follows the same path.

```
a = [1,2,5,18,17,8];

stepSize = 1 / (40 / a.length);
```

then i think i could do something like

```
steps = [];

for( var i = 0; i < 1; i+= stepSize) {
  steps.push(d3.interpolate(a[0],a[1])(i));
}
```

and then repeat that for all the elements.  My question is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "follows the same path"? Do you simply want to repeat the array? `while(steps.length < 40) { steps.push(a); })`

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what your real problem is but I think you want to plot these values and have a smooth curve. In that case use line.interpolate() https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate

In case you DO know what you need and your solution works for you, take this tip:
Never iterate over stepSize. Calculate it once and multiply it with i in every loop where i goes from 0 to 40. This way you work around precision problems.

Your algorithm cleaned up, tested and working:

```
var a = [1,5,12,76,1,2];
var steps = 24;
var ss = (a.length-1) / (steps-1);

var result = new Array(steps);
for (var i=0; i<steps; i++) {
    var progress = ss * i;
    var left = Math.floor(progress);
    var right = Math.ceil(progress);
    var factor = progress - left;
    result[i] = (1 - factor) * a[left] + (factor) * a[right];
    // alternative that actually works the same:
    //result[i] = d3.interpolateNumber(a[left], a[right], factor);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Edited a few times. I hope you get the newest version :-D